# how to make flip animation in ios within views

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation, flip

I have 4 subviews of type UIView which is added in main view. I want to flip these views with smooth flip animation. I have tried but not able to successfully able to complete it. here is the code I have used.

> ```
> [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
> [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
> [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:signUpView cache:YES];
> [UIView commitAnimations];
> ```

it flips the half and promptly displays the other view.
let me know how to this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272179/how-can-i-create-vertical-flip-view-animation-in-ios/17342105#17342105

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try flipping each view separately. Maybe like this

> ```
> [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
> [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
> [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:signInView cache:YES];
> [UIView commitAnimations];
> //
> [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
> [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
> [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:signUpView cache:YES];
> [signInView setHidden:YES];//or you can use remove subview
> [signUpView setHidden:NO];// you can use addsubview
> [UIView commitAnimations];
> ```

Comment: The `beginAnimations:` `commitAnimations:` method of UIView animation has been deprecated since iOS4, the recommendation is to use the block based animation methods instead.

Answer (score 3):

at start im adding my firstView to containerView

```
[self.containerView addSubview:firstView];
```

after that where you need to add you flip transition

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.containerView
                  duration:1
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                animations:^{ [firstView removeFromSuperview]; [self.containerView addSubview:secondView]; }
                completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can even try this

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    animation.delegate = self;
    animation.duration = 1;
    animation.timingFunction = UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut;
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animation.endProgress = 1;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    animation.type = @"oglFlip";

    [yourView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animation"];
```

Some more animation types if you want :

```
animation.type = @"cube";
animation.type = @"suckEffect";
animation.type = @"suckEffect";
animation.type = @"pageCurl";
animation.type = @"pageUnCurl";
animation.type = @"cameraIrisHollowOpen ";
animation.type = @"cameraIrisHollowClose ";
```